# Select With Multiple Where Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to do a select for a whole series of different criteria. I'm essentially going to take today's date, and use it against our invoice table to figure out how we're shaping up this year, compared to the last several years.

In the end, I essentially want to have columns for Year, Year To Date Sales, Quarter To Date Sales, and Month to Date Sales. I've started to create a loop for this, but the problem I'm running into is that it's executing several select's, and not returning me one dataset, but rather 3.

Is the best way to tackle this to build a virtual table, fill it with my results, and then select them out of that?

Here's what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @startDate date, @endDate date;
DECLARE @counter int = 0;


WHILE @counter < 3 BEGIN
    --set start and end dates
    SELECT @startDate = CONVERT(date, (CONVERT(nvarchar, YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR,-1 * @counter, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())))) + '-02-01'));
    SELECT @endDate = DATEADD(YEAR,-1 * @counter, CONVERT (date, GETDATE()));

    --select results
    SELECT YEAR(ib.DateDelivered) [Year], SUM(ib.TotalAmountLessFreight) [YTD Sale]
    FROM InvoiceBase ib
    WHERE ib.DateDelivered < @endDate
        AND ib.DateDelivered > @startDate
    GROUP BY YEAR(ib.DateDelivered);

    --increment
    SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of the resultset you're currently getting and what you'd like to see?

Comment: Right now I'm getting Year and YTD Sales columns in my result set. But I'm getting one result set for 2013, one for 2012, and one for 2011. I'd like to see one resultset with rows for each of those.

Comment: Instead of using counter, change startDate and endDate to encompass all three years you want to query on.

Comment: And just do a select  x where IN (a,b,c)? Great idea!

Comment: Anytime, happy to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it would be in a single query. Try:

```
;with cte as
(select i.*, 
        dateadd(year, datediff(year,DateDelivered,getdate()), getdate()) [YearEnd]
 FROM InvoiceBase i)
select YEAR(DateDelivered) [Year],
       SUM(case when DateDelivered <= YearEnd 
                then TotalAmountLessFreight end) [YTD Sales],
       SUM(case when DateDelivered <= YearEnd and 
                     month(DateDelivered) >= floor((month(YearEnd)+2)/3)*3-2
                then TotalAmountLessFreight end) [QTD Sales],
       SUM(case when DateDelivered <= YearEnd and 
                     datediff(month, DateDelivered, YearEnd) = 0
                then TotalAmountLessFreight end) [MTD Sales]
FROM cte
GROUP BY YEAR(DateDelivered)
```